# Kubernetes: mount certificate to pod

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, ldap

I'd like to deploy an ldap server on my kubernetes cluster. The server itself is up and running, but I'd like to enable SSL encryption for it as well.

I already have `cert-manager` up and running and I also use a multitude of SSL certificates with my ingresses with my HTTP traffic. It would be really nice if I could just use a `CertificateRequest` with my ldap server as well, managed and updated by `cert-manager`.

My problem is I have no idea how to mount a `Certificate` to my kubernetes pod. I know that `cert-manager` creates a secret and puts the certificate data in it. The problem with that is I have no idea of the validity of that certificate this way, and can't remount/reapply the new certificate.

Has anybody done anything like this? Is there a non-hacky way to incorporate ingresses to terminate SSL encryption?